# How to modify a value in jsff dynamically after the application deployed

Tags: oracle-adf

We ran into an issue that we need to modify a value on an ADF jsff page. The value point to a third party library CDN. The location is not accessible so we need to point it to another CDN location. We can change the code, but it will take weeks to go through paperwork and processes for redeployment, so we need a work around to get the customer going.

I tried to modify the value in Google Chrome inspect view but it doesn't seem have any effect, unlike style can be changed on the fly.

Comment: You can't, ADF applications like all java application are compiled and packaged in an .ear archive. You're going to need to redeploy the whole application.